# 'info' and 'history' are undefined in tensorflow.js's model

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, expo, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to build simple machine learning model using `tensorflow.js` library in my expo project. The same code when ran in code sandbox doesn't give any error. By running in visual studio code it gives an error of undefined info,history and logs too. My code is attached below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTfReady: false,
    };
  }

  init() {
    const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [
            tf.layers.dense({
                inputShape: [784],
                units: 32,
                activation: "relu"
            }),
            tf.layers.dense({
                units: 10,
                activation: "softmax"
            })
        ]
    });
    model.weights.forEach(w => {
        console.log(w.name, w.shape);
    });
    model.weights.forEach(w => {
        const newVals = tf.randomNormal(w.shape);
        // w.val is an instance of tf.Variable
        w.val.assign(newVals);
    });
    model.compile({
        optimizer: "sgd",
        loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
        metrics: ["accuracy"]
    });
    const data = tf.randomNormal([100, 784]);
    const labels = tf.randomUniform([100, 10]);

    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
      logs.acc = parseFloat((logs.acc * 100).toFixed(2));
      logs.loss = parseFloat((logs.loss * 100).toFixed(3));

        console.log("Accuracy", logs.acc);
    }

    // Train for 5 epochs with batch size of 32.
    model
        .fit(data, labels, {
            epochs: 5,
            batchSize: 32,
            callbacks: {
                onBatchEnd
            }
        })
        .then(info => {
            console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);
        });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Wait for tf to be ready.
    await tf.ready();
    // Signal to the app that tensorflow.js can now be used.
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true,
    });
  }


  render() {
    //this.init()
    // //
    return (


      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

            <Text>{'Final accuracy', info.history.acc}</Text>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // container: {
  //   flex: 1,
  // },
  buttonContainer: {
   // flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
})
```

Error message is:

> Can't find variable info

Comment: @edkeveked sure...thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info can be added to the state of the application

```
.then(info => {
        this.state = {...this.state, info}
        console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);
    });
```

Display the info only after the model has completed the training by using the conditional rendering

```
render() {
    const {info} = this.state; 
    return (


      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

            {info && <Text>{'Final accuracy', info.history.acc}</Text>}

      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is `console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);` printing something to the console ?

Comment: No...not a single value

Comment: It makes sense because you are not running the model. Before this line : `const {info} = this.state; ` add `this.init()`

Comment: My questions might seem silly but it is giving the same original error i asked earlier make sure to  `await tf.ready()` before calling other methods .

Comment: I added these lines too `history = await this.model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
      shuffle: true,
      });` to avoid the error of "undefined history" now it shows TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'info.history')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202264/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-atia-riaz).